# Apache commons CSV: quoted input doesn't work

Tags: java, apache-commons-csv

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
```

I try to parse a simple csv file with Apache CSV parser. It works fine as long as I don't use quotes. When I try to add a quote to the input

```
"a";42
```

it gives me the error:

```
invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter
```

Here is a simple, complete code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String DATA = "\"a\";12";
        CSVParser csvParser =    
        CSVFormat.EXCEL
            .withIgnoreEmptyLines()
            .withIgnoreHeaderCase()
            .withRecordSeparator('\n').withQuote('"')
            .withEscape('\\').withRecordSeparator(';').withTrim()
            .parse(new StringReader(DATA));
    }

}
```

I simply can't find out what I've missed in the code.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was so trivial I missed it.

I used `withRecordSeparator` instead of `withDelimiter` to set the field separator.

This works as I expected:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String DATA = "\"a\";12";
        CSVParser csvParser =    
        CSVFormat.EXCEL
            .withIgnoreEmptyLines()
            .withIgnoreHeaderCase()
            .withRecordSeparator('\n').withQuote('"')
            .withEscape('\\').withDelimeter(';').withTrim()
            .parse(new StringReader(DATA));
    }
```

}