# Trying to parse a CSV file, delimited by ( , ) and using quotes

Tags: java, android, csv, delimiter

I haven't found much help with this online. I have a CSV file that I want to parse. The delimiter is a comma however I want a comma to be ignored if it's part of a field so I'm using quotes. When I have no commas in my field my method works great. However when I tried it by adding a comma to one of the fields, expecting it to be treated as a single record, I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error. Here is my code. I run it out of AsyncTask. You'll notice I inserted the code -  `r.get(1); r.get(2);` This is for testing only. r.get(1) is the line that throws the error

```
class ParseCsvTask extends AsyncTask<File, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(File... files) {
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            CSVParser parser = null;


            File file = files[0];

            CSVFormat formatter = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader();

            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

                parser = CSVParser.parse(reader, formatter);

                List<CSVRecord> list = parser.getRecords();

                for (CSVRecord r : list) {
                    r.get(1);
                    r.get(2);
                    Competitor competitor = new Competitor(r.get(1), r.get(2));
                    if (!r.get(0).equals("")) {
                        competitor.setMemberNum(r.get(0));
                    }
                    if(!r.get(4).equals("")){
                        competitor.setEmail(r.get(4));
                    }
                    if(!r.get(5).equals("")){
                        competitor.setPhone(r.get(5));
                    }

                    switch (r.get(7)){
                        case "":
                            competitor.setAge(Competitor.Age.ADULT);
                            break;
                        case "Junior":
                            competitor.setAge(Competitor.Age.JUNIOR);
                            break;
                        case "Senior":
                            competitor.setAge(Competitor.Age.SENIOR);
                            break;
                        case "Super Senior":
                            competitor.setAge(Competitor.Age.SUPER_SENIOR);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                    if(r.get(8).equals("")){
                        competitor.setLady(false);
                    } else {
                        competitor.setLady(true);
                    }

                    mImportedComps.add(competitor);

                }

                FileHelper.writeMasterCompetitorsFile(mContext, mImportedComps);

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MasterCompetitorListActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("record", "what is going on");
            } finally {
                try {
                    assert parser != null;
                    parser.close();
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Remember: It works great when I don't use commas in the records. "first name" works fine but if a record says "first , name " I get the error. 
Also, I'm using `*org.apache.commons.csv*`

It was suggested that this question I'm posting was a possible duplicate from this post: [Apache commons CSV: quoted input doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432743/apache-commons-csv-quoted-input-doesnt-work). The fact that the error from this post is `invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter` and mine has to do with an Array index being out of bounds clearly shows we are dealing with different scenarios. I'm not being informed of any invalid chars between delimiters. Something different is happening in my case

Here is the stacktrace that is called when I catch this error:

```
03-05 15:34:44.397 778-778/com.checkinsystems.ez_score D/ViewRootImpl@4ca832c[MasterCompetitorListActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
03-05 15:34:44.479 778-778/com.checkinsystems.ez_score D/ViewRootImpl@4ca832c[MasterCompetitorListActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
03-05 15:34:44.550 778-825/com.checkinsystems.ez_score W/System.err: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
03-05 15:34:44.550 778-825/com.checkinsystems.ez_score W/System.err:     at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord.get(CSVRecord.java:79)
03-05 15:34:44.550 778-825/com.checkinsystems.ez_score W/System.err:     at com.checkinsystems.ez_score.ImportMasterCompsFileFragment$ParseCsvTask.doInBackground(ImportMasterCompsFileFragment.java:186)
03-05 15:34:44.550 778-825/com.checkinsystems.ez_score W/System.err:     at com.checkinsystems.ez_score.ImportMasterCompsFileFragment$ParseCsvTask.doInBackground(ImportMasterCompsFileFragment.java:158)
03-05 15:34:44.550 778-825/com.checkinsystems.ez_score W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
03-05 15:34:44.550 778-825/com.checkinsystems.ez_score W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-05 15:34:44.550 778-825/com.checkinsystems.ez_score W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
03-05 15:34:44.550 778-825/com.checkinsystems.ez_score W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
03-05 15:34:44.550 778-825/com.checkinsystems.ez_score W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
03-05 15:34:44.550 778-825/com.checkinsystems.ez_score W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
03-05 15:34:44.550 778-825/com.checkinsystems.ez_score D/record: what is going on
```

So I've discovered why the `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` error is being thrown. 
I ran the code:

```
for(CSVRecord  r : list){
                    Log.d("record", r.toString());
                }
```

Just after getting the list. I noticed that from some reason, I get a blank record, followed by the correct record. This pattern repeats in other words, I'm somehow getting twice as many records as I need but every other one is blank and that's why I would get the index problem. But I still can't see why I'm getting these blank records. Here is the button onClick that calls the code:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/" + mFileName.getText().toString());

            new ParseCsvTask().execute(file);

        }
```

Here is some logcat output....I've changed the data to hide people's info:

```
03-05 16:25:40.223 13019-13633/com.checkinsystems.ez_score D/record: CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping={member=0, first name=1, last name=2, name=3, email=4, phone=5, squad=6, age=7, gender=8, division=9, power factor=10, class=11, special =12}, recordNumber=1, values=[]]
03-05 16:25:40.223 13019-13633/com.checkinsystems.ez_score D/record: CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping={member=0, first name=1, last name=2, name=3, email=4, phone=5, squad=6, age=7, gender=8, division=9, power factor=10, class=11, special =12}, recordNumber=2, values=[A9J41, Bob, Al,len, Bob Allen, bob@comcast.net, 5555555555, 7, , , Production, Minor, D, ]]
03-05 16:25:40.223 13019-13633/com.checkinsystems.ez_score D/record: CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping={member=0, first name=1, last name=2, name=3, email=4, phone=5, squad=6, age=7, gender=8, division=9, power factor=10, class=11, special =12}, recordNumber=3, values=[]]
03-05 16:25:40.223 13019-13633/com.checkinsystems.ez_score D/record: CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping={member=0, first name=1, last name=2, name=3, email=4, phone=5, squad=6, age=7, gender=8, division=9, power factor=10, class=11, special =12}, recordNumber=4, values=[TY912111, Fred , Jones , Fred Jones , fred@gmail.com, 5555555555, 5, , , Revolver, Minor, C, ]]
```

Keep in mind, this only happens when I add the comma in the middle of the last name of the first record. If I take that comma out, it works fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache commons CSV: quoted input doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432743/apache-commons-csv-quoted-input-doesnt-work)

Comment: I tried with your code, but it works fine for me without any issues.

Comment: @TheGuest how did you come up with your CSV file? When I open the altered version (the one where I add a comma in the middle of one of the fields) in Excel it looks fine but throws the error in my program....the original doesn't

Comment: What do you mean , I can create a .csv file, moreover I have been working with .csv files and java related project for  the last few weeks.

Comment: If you are getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, that means you are using wrong indexes. You should use r.get(0); r.get(1); The index starts from 0. Or else post your sample .csv data

Comment: I'm trying to get to the bottom of the issue I'm having on my end. So what I was asking is how you came up with your file. We must be using different fields because I haven't given all of mine. I'm trying to narrow down the possible differences in your csv and mine. I know this, I'm importing a CSV where I don't use every field in the list but that didn't matter until i added a comma

Comment: @Patric then post some sample csv data

Comment: I can't really post my .csv because it contains real email addresses and phone numbers. The fields are ("member", "first name", "last name", "name", "email", "phone", "squad", "age", "gender", "division", "power factor", "class", and "special") I don't need all these fields right now. My code shows the one's I'm trying to access. Remember r.get(1) is throwing the error and clearly I have a value at index 1 in my csv

Comment: It seems as if adding the comma in, for example, the first name field, somehow splits that field into 2 records thus throwing off the mapping.....but I thought the quotes would take care of that

Comment: @Patric its not the problem with the comma in between double quotes. This is the problem with how you parse the CSV file because this is ArrayIndex exception.

Comment: If the field starts with a `"` then parse it with a function that processes commas as just an ordinary character, and stops when it meets the matching `"` at the end of the field.  You will need to deal with `\"` or `""` if your input includes escaped quotes in quote-delimited fields.

Comment: @rossum I thought about doing that but it kind of defeats the purpose of using the apache.commons.csv library. Plus I'm weary of doing too much processing on the file. These files could get large

Comment: Can you please print the lines to the logcat while you are parsing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! I was using a formatter relying on the `RFC4180` standard. This standard defaults like this:

```
withDelimiter(',')
withQuote('"')
withRecordSeparator("\r\n")
withIgnoreEmptyLines(false)
```

The last attribute, withIgnoreEmptyLines needed to be set to true, otherwise the formatter inserts a blank record after every other record. I'm not exactly sure why inserting blank records between my records would be a standard but I fixed it with this line:

```
CSVFormat formatter = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader()
                    .withIgnoreEmptyLines(true);
```

That's why I was getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`

I hope this helps someone else. Thanks everybody for helping me work through this problem